# Creating a View filter for a CCK field

Tags: views

I have created a custom filter which displays some select options to the user in order to filter a view. However, I am uncertain how to add this using the hook_views_data() hook, being that the table which the filter is being applied to is a CCK table called content_type_sm_mention.

Currently I have the following, which I am not sure is right. What is missing?

```
function smd_views_data()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['content_type_sm_mention']['sentiment'] = array(
      'title' => t('Sentiment'),
      'help' => t('Filter by mention sentiment.'),
      'real field' => 'field_mention_sentiment_value',
      'group' => t('Content'),
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_sentiment',
      ),
    );
    return $data;
}
function smd_views_handlers() {
  return array(
    'info' => array(
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'smd') . '/includes/views',
    ),
    'handlers' => array(
      'views_handler_filter_sentiment' => array(
        'parent' => 'views_handler_filter',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out what is missing, implement `hook_views_data_alter()` and `dsm($data)` in the function to find the right path for your field.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `content_views_data()` in the cck module to see if you can figure out what it is returning.

Comment: If he is asking is probably because he did and he could not figure it out. Why don't you explain what he is doing in his example instead?

Comment: @lordg I am in the same position as you...